# Facebook User follow Lists through graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook User follow Lists through graph api

example lists

https://www.facebook.com/lists/694960453927242

I can't find it :(
thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. The User's who follow a particular User are his subscribers, and the endpoint

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/subscribers
This will show you the total count if you don't have user_subscriptions or friends_subscriptions permission, if you have those you would get name and ids of the Users who follow a User.